# Ipad 2 no more recognized by my Windows 7 computer

Tags: itunes, ipad, windows, driver

I use to do hard reset of my Ipad putting it into DFU mode and doing it from my laptop.
If he used to be recognized, it is no more the case. Neither in DFU or normal mode. I think it is a driver issue but I don't know how to cope with it.

Can you help me getting my Ipad recognized by mylaptop?

Actually it gets recognized in settings > peripherals devices and printers under the name of "Apple mobile device USB driver". But not in Itunes.

I have an Ipad 2 and use Windows 7.

Comment: @Tetsujin The iPad 2 doesn't support iOS 10

Comment: ahh, OK ;-)   ...